# struggling to wait on subscriptions and multiple subscriptions

Tags: meteor, iron-router

i am really struggling with the iron-router waitOn.

I have a number of subscriptions that i would like to waitOn, it doenst seem to me that iron router is waiting on anything.

I have setup a number of subscriptions (main.js), which i would like to load before the application starts:

```
Meteor.subscribe("appointments");
Meteor.subscribe("business");
Meteor.subscribe("clients");
Meteor.subscribe("staff");
```

I have tried almost every configuration i possibly can but i cannot seem to get the "loader" to show itself and wait till all the subscriptions are ready. I have a helper function in the layoutTemplate ('layout') to get a value from the database however findOne() returns undefined/null i assume this is because the router has not waited on the subscriptions...

My router configuration. I would like to understand how i can chain the dependencies or create the dependencies to wait.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',

    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () {
        console.log('Iron router start');
        this.subscribe('clients').wait();
        this.subscribe('staff').wait();
        this.subscribe('appointments').wait();
        this.subscribe('business').wait();
        this.subscribe('calendar').wait();


    },
    action: function() {
        if (this.ready()) {
            this.render('dashboard');
        } else {
            this.render('loading');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing the `waitOn` section like this. Also, I think you can remove the subscriptions from the `main.js` file and write the required/dependent subscriptions in the router's `waitOn` function for that particular route.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () {
        console.log('Iron router start');
        return [        
            Meteor.subscribe('clients'),
            Meteor.subscribe('staff'),
            Meteor.subscribe('appointments'),
            Meteor.subscribe('business'),
            Meteor.subscribe('calendar')
        ]

    },
    action: function() {
        if (this.ready()) {
            this.render('dashboard');
        } else {
            this.render('loading');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The trick was to use the array [ subscription ]. I was struggling to get it to work directly from overall router options [Router.configure()], but managed to get it working directly from this.route('myRoute', { options...

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your subscriptions from onWait into onBeforeAction:

This may work, but i'm not sure. Usually you define the wait params per route not as a global.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        console.log('Iron router start');
        this.subscribe('clients').wait();
        this.subscribe('staff').wait();
        this.subscribe('appointments').wait();
        this.subscribe('business').wait();
        this.subscribe('calendar').wait();


    }
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

If this gives you trouble, try using the `onBeforeAction` above for each of your routes.

Comment: Your comment about creating the define with wait at the route level is very useful. I was not successful doing it as a global - maybe i was doing something wrong.