# Loading and waiting for "global" meteor subscriptions

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

Here's my scenario:

I have a layout template that needs to check to see if a User belongs to at least one Team.  If not, then display a div across the entire site.  A user can only see the teams they belong to, so I created a simple publication that works:  (code samples are CoffeeScript)

```
Meteor.publish 'teams', ->
  return null if !@userId
  Teams.find {'members._id': @userId}
```

This works great and Teams.find().fetch() in console gives expected results.

However, if I put this code in, say, the Template.layout.rendered, it doesn't work.

```
Template.layout.rendered = ->
  teams = Teams.find().fetch()
  hasTeams = teams.length > 0
  if !hasTeams
    ...do stuff..
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the Teams find is async and not loaded when it needs to make the decision.  With a normal template / page I would just use the IronRouter waitOn() but what do I do on the layout?

I could do a waitOn in my router, but since the data is "global" and going to be used everywhere, and because a user could deep link into the site all over the place, I don't want to add that waitOn to EVERY single route.

So what is the proper pattern?  How do I get the meteor client to load global data and wait for the data before running the route?

Answer (score 2):

More thinking and searching found the answer right here on SO: [struggling to wait on subscriptions and multiple subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977367/struggling-to-wait-on-subscriptions-and-multiple-subscriptions)

I changed my Router.configure to this:

```
Router.configure
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
    waitOn: ->
     return [
       Meteor.subscribe('teams')
     ]
```

Multiple subscriptions can be added to the return array, and I believe it will wait on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with iron router subscribing to a chat in two different publications with `waitOn`.

```
Meteor.subscribe('chats')
```

Only when I switched positions of the following publish blocks, would it let me see any data on the route. The following is the correct order for the two.

```
Meteor.publish("chats", function () {
  return Chats.find();
});

Meteor.publish("chats", function(id) {
  return Chats.find({eventRoom: id});
});
```